# R - “ missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed ”

Tags: r

I'm trying to execute the following code in R

```
library(nloptr)

m = 0.00060981
m2 = 0.000109362
m4 = 5.21538E-08
m6 = 4.25E-11
f=function(X){  
  Y = matrix(NA, ncol = 1, nrow = 4)
  mu = X[1]
  S2=X[2]
  S2u = X[3]
  lambda= X[4]
  Y[1] = (mu-(S2/2))-m
  Y[2] = (S2+(lambda*S2u))-m2
  Y[3] = ((3*(S2^2) + 6*(lambda^2)*(S2u^2)+3*(S2u^2)*(lambda) + 6*(lambda)*(S2u)*S2))-m4
  Y[4] = (15*(S2^3) +45*(S2^2)*S2u + 45*(lambda^2)*(S2u^2)*S2 +45*(lambda)*(S2u^2)*S2 +15*(lambda^3)*(S2u^3)+45*(lambda^2)*(S2u^3)+15*lambda*(S2u^3))-m6
  return(Y) 
}
g = function(X){
  return(norm(f(X),'f'))
}
initiale=c( 0.00197,0.022,0.0036,0.8999)
hin = function(X){
h=rep(NA,1)
h[2]>0
h[3]>0
h[1]<h[2]

h
}
ans=auglag(par=initiale,fn=g,hin=hin)
```

But i'm getting this ERROR :

```
Error in if (sig > 1e+05) control.optim$reltol <- 1e-10 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Why am I getting this error, and how to fix the code?

Comment: the code you psoted there has not the line `sig>1e+05` you mention ...can you please post the full code?

Comment: this is the full code i did not use the parameter sig!

Comment: You might want to include the required `library(nloptr)` in your code, if in fact this this the source of the `auglag()` function, though its documented arguments don't seem to match the call you're making?

Comment: Where does `auglag` come from? What's the purpose of the `hin` function, that never uses its `X` argument and does some comparison just for its own sake? Notice that it returns always `NA` and I suspect that this might be related with your issue.

Comment: @csgillespie is right. What do you want the hin function to do? For now, it is creating a single NA value.

Comment: hin = function(X){
h=rep(NA,1)
h[X[2]]>0
h[X[3]]>0
h[X[1]]<h[2]

h
}
the hin function is: introducing the vector of constraints:

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the error message is a result of the `h` function

```
hin = function(X){
       h=rep(NA,1)
       h[2]>0
       h[3]>0
       h[1]<h[2]
       h
 }
```

The value of `h` is **always** `NA` and never changes.